# Cound not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, rasa

I am trying to deploy python application on azure web app. The application couldn't run due to below error
[image]

Please help us with the solution.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The package you used to build the app should make a manifest for you. How did you build the app?

Comment: We created a pipeline in Azure and also created a release which deployed our python application on webapp.

Comment: I checked your question as well as the answer. Please follow the steps and methods to try it first. If you have any questions and need help, we are happy to answer them.

Comment: Hello, If the answer was helpful, Please Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem